# Keep bottom sheet on top of any pages in masterDetailPage Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I'm pretty new on developing apps with xamarin for android and ios in c#. So I created an app for my music station to play music and it contains a MasterDetailPage. On the top left is the menu to select different kinds of pages. But I want to have a static bottom sheet slider form on the bottom where you can start or stop the music which must be displayed all the time and keeps playing while switching other pages. But I also would like to give the user the option to slide this particular form up to see which song is playing and some other info. And the music must keep playing while navigating through other pages.
By now, my app starts with:

`MainPage = new MainPage();`

And in the MainPage.xaml is:

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Test.Views"
            x:Class="Test.Views.MainPage">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <views:MenuPage />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <NavigationPage.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_feed.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </NavigationPage.Icon>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:ItemsPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    
</MasterDetailPage>
```

And then it calls MenuPage which loads the menu and stuff.

What is the best way and how can I do this?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXU41.gif)

Comment: Do you mean the botton sheet do the thing of Menu page? Do you wat to do something like screenshot: https://imgur.com/HeY3j0Y Use the bottom sheet as Menu Page?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Yes indeed. But also visible on all pages when I open another page. I would like to keep that slider always visible because it shows the streaming music player and track information. So I think it stops playing when another page is displayed and the user cannot control it than, eg stop or pause the music. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the bottom sheet, you could refer to the code below.

```
  <RelativeLayout>

    <StackLayout Padding="10,20,0,0">
        <Label Text="Page7" />
    </StackLayout>
    <Frame
        x:Name="bottomSheet"
        Padding="1,4,1,0"
        BackgroundColor="#faf9f8"
        CornerRadius="8"
        HasShadow="true"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                               Property=Height,
                                                               Factor=1,
                                                               Constant=0}"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                              Property=Width,
                                                              Factor=1,
                                                              Constant=0}"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                          Property=Height,
                                                          Factor=.9,
                                                          Constant=0}">
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="OnPanUpdated" />
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <StackLayout Spacing="5">
            <BoxView
                BackgroundColor="Gray"
                CornerRadius="2"
                HeightRequest="5"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                WidthRequest="50" />
            <SearchBar
                x:Name="SearchBox"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                Focused="SearchBar_Focused"
                Placeholder="Search by Ingredient"
                 />
            <StackLayout x:Name="GridFilter">
                <Button />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code Behind:

```
public Page7()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public double getProportionCoordinate(double proportion)
    {
        return proportion * Height;
    }

    private void SearchBar_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        GridFilter.IsVisible = true;
        openBottomSheet();
    }
    void openBottomSheet()
    {
        var finalTranslation = Math.Max(Math.Min(0, -1000), -Math.Abs(getProportionCoordinate(.85)));
        bottomSheet.TranslateTo(bottomSheet.X, finalTranslation, 150, Easing.SpringIn);
    }
    // Important Code Lives Below
    double x, y;
    private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle the pan
        switch (e.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                // Translate and ensure we don't y + e.TotalY pan beyond the wrapped user interface element bounds.
                var translateY = Math.Max(Math.Min(0, y + e.TotalY), -Math.Abs((Height * .25) - Height));
                bottomSheet.TranslateTo(bottomSheet.X, translateY, 20);
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                // Store the translation applied during the pan
                y = bottomSheet.TranslationY;

                //at the end of the event - snap to the closest location
                var finalTranslation = Math.Max(Math.Min(0, -1000), -Math.Abs(getClosestLockState(e.TotalY + y)));

                //depending on Swipe Up or Down - change the snapping animation
                if (isSwipeUp(e))
                {
                    bottomSheet.TranslateTo(bottomSheet.X, finalTranslation, 250, Easing.SpringIn);
                }
                else
                {
                    bottomSheet.TranslateTo(bottomSheet.X, finalTranslation, 250, Easing.SpringOut);
                }

                //dismiss the keyboard after a transition
                SearchBox.Unfocus();
                y = bottomSheet.TranslationY;

                break;

        }
    }

    public bool isSwipeUp(PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.TotalY < 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    //TO-DO: Make this cleaner
    public double getClosestLockState(double TranslationY)
    {
        //Play with these values to adjust the locking motions - this will change depending on the amount of content ona  apge
        var lockStates = new double[] { 0, .5, .85 };

        //get the current proportion of the sheet in relation to the screen
        var distance = Math.Abs(TranslationY);
        var currentProportion = distance / Height;

        //calculate which lockstate it's the closest to
        var smallestDistance = 10000.0;
        var closestIndex = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < lockStates.Length; i++)
        {
            var state = lockStates[i];
            var absoluteDistance = Math.Abs(state - currentProportion);
            if (absoluteDistance < smallestDistance)
            {
                smallestDistance = absoluteDistance;
                closestIndex = i;
            }
        }

        var selectedLockState = lockStates[closestIndex];
        var TranslateToLockState = getProportionCoordinate(selectedLockState);

        return TranslateToLockState;
    }
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Ok, but if I have a MasterDetailPage where all my pages are being displayed? Works that the same?

Comment: You could add the code for the details page or create a base page with the bottom sheet.

Comment: I have used this option. Everything working well but when using a ListView inside StackLayout (Main Body content) last two items not showing